# Continuity for nonequivalent norms in a linear space

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

If two norms $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ defined on the same linear space $L$ are not equivalent. Is it possible to define a linear functional (which is not identically zero) $f:L\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous for both norms?

Comment: I'm sure you will not be happy with the zero functional, would you?

Comment: @Ruy I forgot to add that condition.

Comment: If there is a counter-example, it can only happen when $L$ is infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly,  the questioner asks whether **every**  vector space equipped with two norms  admits a
nonzero linear functional  which is continuous relative to both norms.

I must say right away that I don't have an answer but, having spent some time puzzling about it, I found a very strange
equivalent condition that a counter-example  must satisfy and I'd like to share this here.

To fix notation let $X$ be our vector space and let $\Vert \cdot \Vert _1$ and $\Vert \cdot \Vert _2$ be two norms on $X$.

Here is what I found:
a necessary and sufficient condition for there **not to be** any nonzero linear functional which is continuous relative to
both $\Vert \cdot \Vert _1$ and $\Vert \cdot \Vert _2$ is that, for every $x$ in $X$, there are vectors $y$ and $z$ in $X$, such that

- $x=y+z$,
- $\Vert y\Vert _1<1$,  and
- $\Vert z\Vert _2<1$.

Here is the proof:  suppose that the above condition is satisfied and, arguing by contradiction, that  there exists a nonzero
continuous linear functional relative to both norms.

By multiplying $f$ by a small enough number, we may assume that
the norm of $f$ is no bigger than 1 relative to both norms.  Since $f$ is nonzero, we may choose a vector $x$ such that
$f(x)\neq 0$, and again by scaling, we may assume that $f(x)=2$.   Write $x=y+z$, with  $\Vert y\Vert _1, \Vert z\Vert _2<1$,   and
observe that
$$
  2 = |f(x)| \leq    |f(y)| + |f(z)| \leq  \Vert y\Vert _1 + \Vert z\Vert _2  < 1+1,
  $$
a contradiction.

Conversely, suppose that there is no simultaneosly continuous linear functional and denote the open unit ball relative
to $\Vert \cdot \Vert _i$ by $B_i$.  Also let
$$
  B = B_1+B_2.
  $$
Our goal is thus to prove that $B=X$.   In any event, notice that $B$ is a convex, absorbing and balanced set, so we
may consider the so called Minkowsky functional, namely
$$
  p(x) = \inf\big\{|\lambda | : \lambda \in  {\mathbb R}\setminus \{0\},\ \lambda ^{-1} x\in  B\big\}.
  $$
Again arguing by contradiction, suppose that $B\neq X$, so we may pick some $x_0$ lying outside $B$, in which case clearly $p(x_0)\geq 1$.

Considering the linear functional defined on ${\mathbb R}x_0$ by $f(\lambda x_0)=\lambda $, we then see that
$$
  |f(\lambda x_0)| = |\lambda | \leq  |\lambda |p(x_0) = p(\lambda x_0),
  $$
so Hahn-Banach provides a linear functional $g$ on $X$,  extending $f$,  and satisfying $|g(x)|\leq p(x)$ for all $x$ in
$X$.

Observing that $p\leq 1$ on either $B_1$ or $B_2$, we deduce that
$$
  \sup_{x\in B_i}|g(x)| \leq 1,
  $$
which implies that $g$ is continuous for both norms, a contradiction.